# Создание конструктора класса

Tags: java, ооп, классы, конструктор

В домашнем задании нужно создать новый конструктор. В проекте уже существует один, который генерирует кошек. Необходимо создать еще один, который будет генерировать уже котят.

Я без тени сомнения начал было писать новый, но вдруг обнаружил что при этом отваливается и тот что уже есть, при этом перестают работать оба.
Ниже представлен оригинальный конструктор, что уже был в проекте:

```
public Cat()
{
    weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
    originWeight = weight;
    minWeight = 1000.0;
    maxWeight = 9000.0;
}
```

Я решил добавить еще один:

```
public Cat()
{
    weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
    originWeight = weight;
    minWeight = 1000.0;
    maxWeight = 9000.0;
}

public Kitten()
{
    weight = 100 + 200 * Math.random();
    originWeight = weight;
    minWeight = 100.0;
    maxWeight = 200.0;
}
```

При добавлении `Kitten`, среда разработки сразу сообщает что

> Constructor `Cat` is never used,

а в `Kitten`

> invalid method declaration, return type required

Возможно я просто что-то не так делаю, но меня очень сильно смущает, что я по сути не выдумал ничего нового, а решил сделать по уже готовому шаблону, немного видоизменив параметры, а все разваливается.

Comment: Вы создали не второй конструктор, а просто метод и IDE требует указать возвращаемый тип для него. А конструктор должен иметь то же имя, что и класс, и чтобы создать ещё один конструтор, он должен иметь другую сигнатуру (прочитайте про перегрузку методов).

Comment: Унаследуйте конструктор Kitten от конструктора Cat, тогда конструктор Kitten будет содержать те же параметры что и конструктор Cat, плюс если захотите можете в конструктор Kitten добавить еще переменные, например, если родившийся котенок будет с грыжей.

Comment: @McDaggen
Что то я тут уже совсем запутался.
Как правильно мне тогда следует начать писать ?
public Kitten....

И не выйдет так, что передваться будут те же параметры с теми же значениями ?.

Comment: `Конструктор` так-же не может быть одинаковым, но может писаться с разными типами, к примеру ваш класс, можно было назвать `Животные`, а в конструктор передавать `Имя` животного), ну а в самом классе, описать виды животных и их характеристик.

Comment: Всё правильно пишут комментаторы выши - констуктор это метод, который по названию совпадает с именем класса. Конструктор Kitten вы имеете право создать только тогда, когда имеете класс Kitten. А так вы говорите, буквально - создай мне котёнка, но я тебе не дам ни чертёж ни пояснительную записку. Естественно компилятор заругается.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Не могли бы тогда на примере показать как я должен добавить что-то новое ?
То что добрые люди написали ниже, как то уж совсем сильно видоизменяют то что уже было. Я уверен что эти варианты работают и правильно оформлены, но я считаю что дабы хоть чему то научиться, должен учиться писать все самостоятельно, и понять сам принцип этого.
А выходит что хватай готовый результат, толком не понимай почему он написан именно так и пользуйся.
Более конкретно:
Как должен начинаться новый метод, что бы компилятор его принял ?

Comment: @АндрейЗабродин объясняю, то что вам уже пояснили. Вы добавили public Kitten()... компилятор читает название, и думает: ага Kitten≇Cat, значит это не конструктор, значит это метод. Раз метод, должен быть тип возвращаемого значения, double, int, void или объект. Ага - тип возвращаемого значения не указан, - говорит компилятор. - я дальше читать не буду.

Answer (score 3):

> Kitten "invalid method declaration, return type required"

вы создали метод класса `Cat`, а не конструктор. Конструктор имеет название класса и не возвращает результат. В то время как метод возвращает и если метод не содержит утверждения `return`, то его надо пометить как `void`.

---

Чтобы использовать метод для создания объекта `Cat` можно использовать возвращаемое значение

```
public Cat Kitten()
{
    Cat c = new Cat();
    c.weight = 100 + 200 * Math.random();
    c.originWeight = c.weight;
    c.minWeight = 100.0;
    c.maxWeight = 200.0;
    return c;
}
```

---

Только тут возникает проблема, так как в конструкторе `Cat()` уже инициализированы поля. Чтобы не делать повторную инициализацию, можно создать новый конструктор, который будет принимать параметр.

```
public Cat() {
  this(false);
}

public Cat(boolean isKitten) {
    if (isKitten) {
      weight = 100 + 200 * Math.random();
      originWeight = weight;
      minWeight = 100.0;
      maxWeight = 200.0;
    } else {
      weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
      originWeight = weight;
      minWeight = 1000.0;
      maxWeight = 9000.0;
    }
}

public Cat Kitten() {
    Cat c = new Cat(true);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1ое. Конструктор не должен содержать никакой сложной логики (по типу генерации велечин). Передавате это параметрами в конструктор Cat.

2ое. Стоит унаследовать Kitten от Cat и в конструкторе Kitten 1-ой строчкой прописать super(...), куда передать нужные параметры

```
public class Cat {
    double weight;
    double minWeight;
    double maxWeight;

    public Cat(double weight, double minWweight, double maxWeight) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.minWeight = minWweight;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
    }
}

public class Kitten extends Cat {
    public Kitten(double weight, double minWeight, double maxWeight) {
        super(weight, minWeight, maxWeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Здоровое решение. Естественно, что класс котёнка надо наследовать от кота.

Comment: Кого от кого наследовать должно определяться постановкой задачи и целями, которые должны достигаться в дальнейшем. Можно и наоборот, унаследовать кота от котенка. Разницы нет. Но, чисто по смыслу обсуждаемой задачи, я бы не стал вообще делать класс-наследник, так как инициализация экземпляра кота может начаться с котенка...

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще сильно подозреваю, что преподователь автора вопроса имел ввиду не операцию наследования, а операцию перегрузки конструктора. То есть - первый конструктор генерит кошек, другой - который инициализиурется к примеру числом, и генерирует котят. Я предлагаю добавить второй конструктор класса Cat, который будет вызываться числом:

```
public class Cat {
    double weight;
    double minWeight;
    double maxWeight;

//Конструктор кошек  
 public Cat() //Сработает при инициализации Cat cat = new Cat();
 {
   weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
   originWeight = weight;
   minWeight = 1000.0;
   maxWeight = 9000.0;
 }

 //Конструктор котят, все параметры уменьшены в 1...5 раз, по сравнению с 
 //размерами кошек  
 public Cat(int x) //Сработает при инициализации Cat cat = new Cat(4);
 { 
   x = x%3+3;       
   weight = (1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random())/x;
   originWeight = weight/x;
   minWeight = 1000.0/x;
   maxWeight = 9000.0/x;
 }        
}
```